# RSpec - WrongScopeError: expect is not available on an example group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm getting this error:

> method_missing': `expect` is not available on an example group (e.g.
>   a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within
>   individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in
>   the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
>   (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)

For this spec:

```
describe 'canary test' do
    expect(true).to be true
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap the test inside a block, e.g. you could have:

```
describe 'canary test' do
  it 'it true' do
    expect(true).to be true
  end
end
```